# i cant install psutil. errors-

Tags: python, psutil

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ossie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2k5r_jgp\\psutil_fa318508a4d548219c112ce699e59d0a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ossie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2k5r_jgp\\psutil_fa318508a4d548219c112ce699e59d0a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eq3dhtyy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
     cwd: C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2k5r_jgp\psutil_fa318508a4d548219c112ce699e59d0a\
Complete output (38 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
running build_ext
building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2k5r_jgp\psutil_fa318508a4d548219c112ce699e59d0a\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2k5r_jgp\psutil_fa318508a4d548219c112ce699e59d0a\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eq3dhtyy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ossie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: also whenever i try to install visual c++ 14 it says setup failed

Comment: How did the setup fail?  Do you have admin privileges on your computer?  You should be able to install Visual C++ Express Edition.